# Precision and Recall on PySpark DecisionTree model diverges from manual results

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I trained a `DecisionTree` model on a PySpark dataframe. The resulting dataframe is simulated below:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(
    [
        (0., 1.), 
        (0., 0.), 
        (0., 0.), 
        (1., 1.), 
        (1.,0.), 
        (1.,0.),
        (1.,1.),
        (1.,1.)
    ]
)
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, ["prediction", "target_index"])
df.show()
+----------+------------+
|prediction|target_index|
+----------+------------+
|       0.0|         1.0|
|       0.0|         0.0|
|       0.0|         0.0|
|       1.0|         1.0|
|       1.0|         0.0|
|       1.0|         0.0|
|       1.0|         1.0|
|       1.0|         1.0|
+----------+------------+
```

So let's calculate a metric, recall:

```
metricsp = MulticlassMetrics(df.rdd)
print metricsp.recall()
0.625
```

Ok. Let's try to confirm that this is correct:

```
tp = df[(df.target_index == 1) & (df.prediction == 1)].count()
tn = df[(df.target_index == 0) & (df.prediction == 0)].count()
fp = df[(df.target_index == 0) & (df.prediction == 1)].count()
fn = df[(df.target_index == 1) & (df.prediction == 0)].count()
print "True Positives:", tp
print "True Negatives:", tn
print "False Positives:", fp
print "False Negatives:", fn
print "Total", df.count()
True Positives: 3
True Negatives: 2
False Positives: 2
False Negatives: 1
Total 8
```

and calculate recall:

```
r = float(tp)/(tp + fn)
print "recall", r

recall 0.75
```

and the results differ. What I'm doing wrong?

BTW, all functions from the `Metrics` class are giving the same results:

```
print metricsp.recall()
print metricsp.precision()
print metricsp.fMeasure()
0.625
0.625
0.625
```

Comment: Your headers are jumbled up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are using MultiClassMetrics for processing output of a Binary classifier. From the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/mllib/evaluation/MulticlassMetrics.html):

```
recall()
Returns recall (equals to precision for multiclass classifier because sum of all false positives is equal to sum of all false negatives)
```

To get correct results, use recall(label=1):

```
>>> print metricsp.recall(label=1)
0.75
```

BTW, headers in your `df.show()` seem to be jumbled up, it should be:

```
+----------+------------+
|prediction|target_index|
+----------+------------+
|       0.0|         1.0|
|       0.0|         0.0|
|       0.0|         0.0|
|       1.0|         1.0|
|       1.0|         0.0|
|       1.0|         0.0|
|       1.0|         1.0|
|       1.0|         1.0|
+----------+------------+
```